# How to read/use mouse from a boot loader?

Tags: assembly, mouse, nasm, bootloader

I want to use mouse from a boot loader, but the int33h is not working, (DOS interrupt, and there is no DOS booting),so can you help me, how can I read the mouse position, status, etc without using int33h?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of system?  If it's a USB mouse, you have some chores ahead of you.

Answer (score 1):

This might help: http://wiki.osdev.org/Mouse_Input

(found indirectly from Mike's answer in this SO thread: [Develop a Bootloader In Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120297/develop-a-bootloader-in-assembly))